# How to temporarily disable flycheck while running an elisp function that inserts a large amount of text into the buffer

Tags: flycheck

I often write elisp functions for large sections of boilerplate code.  I am currently writing some Java and using Meghanda mode which uses Flycheck.  However, when inserting these large chunks of text, I often break the Java syntax checker temporarily, so I would like to bind some variable in my Elisp code (or call some "toggle" function) to suppress flychecking on the code.  Currently the code dies because flycheck throws an error (and I don't care about that error until I am done).

```lisp
(defun insert-foo (param)
  (interactive "sparam:")
  (let ((turn-fly-check-off t))
    (insert "20 lines of code substituting param")))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks for that pointer.  How do you ask a question specifically about how to write something in elisp, when you don't know what you will be writing is a function or a variable (or perhaps a macro)?  That is I don't want to use "customize" or some key-binding, but something that I will write in elisp.

Comment: You ask a specific question. "How do I do XYZ in Elisp?" "How can I suppress flycheck interference, using Elisp?" Or whatever the specific question is.

Comment: Yes, but what tag do I use?

Comment: Whatever tags apply specifically to what you're trying to do. Find a file? Search for something? Define a keymap? Iterate? Write conditional code? Write an Elisp macro? There are specific tags for all kinds of things you might be trying to do. Go to the tags page to see what's already available.